# How to implement a certain query in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I wanted to run a query, "Find me the item with smallest 'id' which is larger than some number" ?
Is it possible in dynamodb ?
And how to do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I needed it for a problem that I am doing. If writing such a query is possible in dynamodb then it would reduce my efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, a DynamoDB table can have 2 types of keys: hash keys, or hash+range keys
When you run a query, you need to specify the hash key for the item that you are looking for. If your table has a key of type hash+range, you will automatically get the results back with the range attribute sorted. Your `Query` request can also optionally add a `KeyCondition` on the range attribute so that you can require that it be larger than some number.  So, yes, what you are looking for is possible, assuming that you design your table appropriately.

For more info, check out the following links:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html